# How can I tell how big my file will be after gzipping, on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, gzip, minify

I can minify on Windows with Node + UglifyJS. So I can say "this change adds 123 bytes after minification."

But I'd like to be able to saying "this changes adds 23 bytes after minification + gzipping."

How can I find out how gzipping will affect my file's size, easily, on Windows?

Comment: I think the only way is to actually gzip the file. I don't think there is a better way - but I'm happy to be proven wrong

Comment: Yeah, you basically have to gzip it to find out; the compression ratio depends on the data being compressed. For instance, jpeg or mp3 data doesn't get compressed much by gzip, since it's already compressed data, whereas a txt file can be compressed quite a bit.

Comment: It would be simple to just request that file over HTTP. Look at the response header and it will tell you exactly how many bytes after gzip.  Most browsers have developer tools that will enable you to inspect HTTP response headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use UnxTools (http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/) for windows

In the zip file, you can simply unpack /usr/local/wbin folder to any location on your disc (I use C:/Tools/Unx and make it part of the PATH.

There is gzip tool. Simply use "gzip myscript.js" to get it gzipped. You can easily include the tools into command line process to automate the gzipping and size comparison.

UPDATE: Here is the small `checkgzip.cmd` file I use with UnxTools to see the difference:

```
@echo off
dir *.js | grep -Ei [0-9][0-9]/
gzip *.js
dir *.gz | grep -Ei [0-9][0-9]/
gunzip *.gz
```

Typical output then looks like this with file lengths in bytes to the right from the files:

```
C:\Tmp\>checkgzip
11/02/2012  09:32 PM             1,026 test.js
11/02/2012  09:32 PM               335 test.js.gz
```

Files are back intact after the run.

Answer (score 0):

Without sending it through a server that will gZip the file you just use 7Zip or Winzip to compress the file. While it's not necessarily the *exact* zip algorithm the browser is using you'll get a very good approximation of how big the file will be over the wire.

Like others pointed out, the type of file will depend on how much compression you'll actually get.